# Implementing a symbol table for a compiler in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, symbols

I am currently developing a small compiler for a language for problem definitions. You can imagine a bastard child of Lisp and Prolog. Now, to the case:

[Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) is a base class from which 3 classes inherit: A,B,C.

I made a lexer and parser with ANTLR3C, which gives me an AST tree. I traverse the tree and when I find a function of type A, I create an object of type A with the data from the tree, and a sym_register object to hold it:

```c
#ifndef SYM_REGISTER_H
#define SYM_REGISTER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

enum class Symbol_type : int { T_A, T_B, T_C, T_D };

class sym_register {
    public:
        std::string name;
        Symbol_type type;
        std::shared_ptr<Functor> declaration;
        std::vector < InstancedFunctor > result;

        sym_register(std::string n, Symbol_type t, std::shared_ptr<Functor> p){ 
            name = n; type = t; declaration = p;
        }   
};

#endif
```

The Symbol_type enum class gives me the info of what kind of object is std::shared_ptr declaration; pointing to, so I should be able to retrieve the full information of the object.

This is how I store the symbols in my main Problem class:

```c
class Problem {
    std::map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<sym_register> > sym_table;
};
```

My problem is when I try to retrieve the symbols from the table, as I am not able to get the "declaration" attribute to its original class, I've tried using static_cast and reinterpret_cast with no results.

So, here I have various questions:

1. Is the "extra" information from the inherited classes lost when I store a pointer to an object of type A on a std::shared_ptr ?
2. Should I go for a switch and an (unsafe) explicit conversion?
3. Should I store pointers to NULL (a-la C) instead of std::shared_ptr ?
4. What is the correct way to do it?

EDIT: I basically want to be able to do:

```c
std::shared_ptr<A> foo = Problem.getSymbol("objectWithTypeA"); 
// and so on with the rest of the class hierarchy ...
```

EDIT2: The compilation errors are:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> foo = it.second->declaration; 
// error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr<Functor>’ 
// to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<A>’ requested

std::shared_ptr<A> foo(reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<A> >(it.second->declaration));
// error: invalid cast from type ‘std::shared_ptr<Functor>’
// to type ‘std::shared_ptr<A>’

std::shared_ptr<A> foo(static_cast<std::shared_ptr<A> >(it.second->declaration));
// error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<A>::shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<Functor>&)’
// note: candidates are:
// long list of template instantiations with a final
// note:   no known conversion for argument 1 
// from ‘std::shared_ptr<Functor>’ to ‘const std::shared_ptr<A>&’

std::shared_ptr<A> foo(static_cast<A*>(it.second->declaration));
// error: invalid static_cast from type ‘std::shared_ptr<Functor>’ to type ‘A*’

std::shared_ptr<A> foo(reinterpret_cast<A*>(it.second->declaration));
// error: invalid cast from type ‘std::shared_ptr<Functor>’ to type ‘A*’
```

Comment: What do you mean with not being able to get the "declaration" attribute? Is there a compilation error or a runtime error?

Comment: Basically compilation errors, when I try to cast the "declaration" attribute to its original class (stored in the "type" attribute.

Comment: And what is the compilation error?

Comment: "Basically" compilation errors? The exact words of the errors is relevant, as is the code where you attempt the cast. (And casting is very non-OOP.)

Comment: I edited the post with some of the errors I get when I try to make the cast. @molbdnilo, in your opinion what would be the correct OOP way of implementing a symbol table? I could not think of a better way myself.

Comment: General rule of thumb: `reinterpret_cast` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you looking for: `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<>` ?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

```
std::shared_ptr<A> foo = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<A>( 
                             Problem.getSymbol("objectWithTypeA") );
```

Where `Problem.getSymbol("objectWithTypeA")`returns a `std::shared_ptr<Functor>`

Note that if the object is not of type `A` the returned shared_ptr will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

A "quick and dirty" solution for this problem is doing this:

```
shared_ptr<A> foo = shared_ptr<A>((A *)&*it.second->declaration);
```

but I feel that it should be a better/cleaner/safer solution to this problem (with or without this particular implementation).

Comment: Please don't use C-casts in C++ code. They convey less meaning and are harder to search for.

Comment: Yes RedX, that is what I wanted to avoid. fjardon has the solution for my problem :)